# OpenpyXL: Runtime Error 6 Overflow

Tags: vba, excel, openpyxl

I have a program utilizing openpyxl that opens two existing Excel files.  One is a simple worksheet with data that needs to be copied into the other file, which is a workbook containing many worksheets and with VBA macros that use this copied data.  When the VBA code runs, though, I get a Runtime Error 6 overflow.  The strange thing is that if I manually copy all of the required cells into the workbook, the macros run without a hitch.  But when this process is automated, even though the values in the cells are identical, this error pops up.  Below is the code which transcribes the data from one worksheet to the other.

```
def transcribe_client_data_to_workbooks():
    _active_sheet_index = 5
    for client in set(cdict.values()):
        report_path = r'C:\Program Files\Notepad++\reports' + '\\' + 
        string.replace(client,'/','-') + '_report.csv'
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Bucket-Asset Allocation Model.xlsm', 
             read_only = False, keep_vba = True)
        ws = wb.active
        with open(report_path, 'rU') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row_index, row in enumerate(reader):
                for column_index, cell in enumerate(row):
                    column_letter = get_column_letter((column_index+1))
                    ws[column_letter+str(row_index+1)] = cell
            f.close()
        wb.save('C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\workbooks\\' + 
        string.replace(client,'/','-') + '_workbook.xlsm')
```

I don't understand why I would receive this error message when this data is automatically copied in, but not when I copy/paste manually. I open the same workbook template each iteration and then save it as a new one after the appropriate data has been copied over.  For reference, here is the section of VBA code where the error occurs.

```
Do Until Sheets("Raw Data").Cells(crow, 1).Value = Empty
                aNumber = Sheets("Raw Data").Cells(crow, 1).Value
                ticker = Sheets("Raw Data").Cells(crow, 9).Value
                security = Sheets("Raw Data").Cells(crow, 8).Value
                mValue = Sheets("Raw Data").Cells(crow, 12).Value
                bAmt = Sheets("Raw Data").Cells(crow, 18).Value
                uGain = Sheets("Raw Data").Cells(crow, 20).Value
                    Do Until Sheets("Accounts").Cells(acrow, 1).Value = aNumber
                    acrow = acrow + 1
                    Loop
```

Specifically it occurs on the line that increments acrow:
acrow = acrow + 1
I tried changing acrow from an integer to a long, but that just causes the program to run indefinitely  until I click or cancel it, at which point I receive Run-time error '1004', Application defined or object-defined error, on the line directly preceding the increment of acrow.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So, there is no exception when the Python code runs?

Comment: Not at all.  It generates the new, filled-in workbooks in the destination folder without raising any errors.  The workbooks that it produces are identical to the template that I loaded except with additional data.  I have keep_vba set to true but is it possible that some aspect of the workbook isn't being preserved?  Let me know if you need more of the VBA code.

Comment: additionally I've just noticed that the workbook template is 488 KB itself, whereas the filled in copies are ~180 KB.  All of the macros seem to be preserved, but does this indicate I'm losing important functionality when loading and resaving the template?

Comment: Where is `acrow` inititalized? It seems that `Sheets("Accounts").Cells(acrow, 1).Value = aNumber` is always false and you thus have an infinite loop. In any event, a VBA linear search for a value in a column is poor VBA. It is better to use the `Find` method of a `Range` object. That can lead to a dramatic improvement of run-time.

Comment: acrow is initialized as an Integer, beginning at 2. I didn't write the VBA side of things so I'm not totally sure what that loop is supposed to be doing, not to mention I'm not VBA literate.  but you're right, it does seem to be not terminating and causing the overflow.  It looks like it continues looping until it comes across an identical account number, or until it hits an empty cell.  I just don't get why it would terminate when I manually enter the data but not when the same data is automatically entered..

Comment: So I've realized that aNumber is of type Variant.  Which in excel can be anything except for a fixed length string.  Since account numbers occasionally started with 1 or two letters, I was writing them as strings into that field!  This is probably why the comparison is never evaluating true! What other type could I cast the account numbers to so that they are compatible with the excel variant type?  They are usually of the format 555555555 or X555555555

Answer (score 0):

John Coleman was correct about the location of the overflow.  The issue was that I was writing aNumber as strings and aNumber was declared in the VBA as Variant type, which according to the docs can represent anything other than a fixed length string.  I simply changed my strategy and wrote account numbers as integers which resolved the problem.